# Add properties folder to weblogic server classpath

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I want to add a folder to Weblogic server classpath.

Idea is that, i will place all my property files in this folder.When i deploy my Web-application in weblogic, server will read all properties files from this folder only making application having a single place for all property files.

I have changed the **startWebLogic.cmd** script and added the below line,**But no use**.

**set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\my_domain\properties**

Iam running my application on windows machine.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: How are you loading the properties from your application?

Answer (score 4):

It's an old thread though I have the solution; instead of adding classpath into the `startWebLogic.cmd` add it into `setDomainEnv.cmd`. I have created a folder **properties** into the path `%DOMAIN_HOME%`. For my machine the `%DOMAIN_HOME%` is actually C:\Users\TapasB\Development\Workspaces\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.7.40.64.93\DefaultDomain.

Then at the bottom of the `setDomainEnv.cmd` just above the code:

```
if NOT "%JAVA_VENDOR%"=="BEA" (
    set JAVA_VM=%JAVA_VM% %JAVA_DEBUG% %JAVA_PROFILE%
) else (
    set JAVA_VM=%JAVA_VM% %JAVA_DEBUG% %JAVA_PROFILE%
)
```

I have added `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%DOMAIN_HOME%\properties;`

So it looks like:

[image]

And this works.

Answer (score 0):

To add a folder to the AppClasspath add a line like this to the end of  C:\Programme\wls1211_dev\domains\base_domain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Programme\wls1211_dev\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\classpath
```

This will add the Folder config/classpath to your managed server classpath, so all files located there will be available to your application.

Comment: I have used the same way as you described which I have already specified in my question.